# IF - condition with char comparison not working in C

Tags: c

**I really don't know what's the mistake. It seems to be right, doesn't it?**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char op;

   printf("Type in operator (+,-,/,*):");
   scanf("%i",&op);

   if(op == '+')
   {
      printf("You entered a plus");
   }

   system("pause"); 
   return 0;
}
```

I expected it to print "You entered a plus" when entering a +.
It does not.

*I'm kinda new to C.
Thanks in advance :)*

Comment: Since you're new to C, please try to avoid picking up bad habits - like calling [`system("pause")`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong).

Comment: Also, enable all warnings and debugging info in your compiler (e.g. use `gcc -Wall -g` on Linux), improve the code till no warnings are given, and learn how to use the debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `if` condition is fine. The problem is the `scanf()` format, which should be

```
scanf("%c",&op);
```

(`%i` reads an integer whereas `%c` reads a `char`.)

Comment: thank you for the very fast answer, it works now :)
but another issue: when i want the user to enter an integer before entering the char, the console jumps over it and doesn't give him even a try to enter... like: 
printf("Enter number:");
scanf("%i",&number);
printf("Enter char:");
scanf("%c",&op);

Comment: what's the matter with that? I'm trying to make a calculator. After entering the last Integer-number it overjumps the query for entering an operator (as char). ??

Comment: The new line character `'\n'` from when you pressed ENTER after typing the integer is still there and the `scanf` reads that instead of the operator. Think about how you can use a loop to skip newline characters.

Comment: You may want to learn about `getc` and `getchar` ... Also remember that `stdin` (and also `stdout`) are often "line buffered"

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%i", &op);
```

You are expecting an integer. So, when you write a character and press `<Enter>`, `scanf` fails (you can check its return value to see it):

```
if (scanf("%i", &op) != 1)
{
    /* Treat the error. */
}
```

Use rather `%c` format in `scanf` to read characters:

```
scanf("%c", &op);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with wrong format specifier

```
//In scanf instead of 
scanf("%i",&op);
// you have to provide 
scanf("%c",&op);

%i use for reading integer whereas %c use for reading char.
```